# How can I get Unix like paths working in Bash on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For those unfamiliar with [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/), it is a port of *nix programs to Windows. There, I could do things like:

```
$ some-prog ~/.profile
$ some-prog /c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

`some-prog` could be any binary, regardless of whether they were general Windows programs or programs compiled with compilers in msys2. The paths would be transparently translated, thus giving that very *nix-ish vibe even when working with programs not part of msys2.

Currently, I'm checking out WSL/"Bash on Windows" (Creators Update), and I seem to have a problem.

For a Linux program, everything works fine:

```
~ $ nano ~/.
```

As expected, nano opens up with contents of `~/.profile`.

When trying to invoke a Windows program though, there's an error:

```
~ $ "/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe" ~/.profile
Unable to translate current working directory. Using C:\Users\Admin
```

And it opens up `C:\home\<wsl_username>\.profile` in Sublime Text, whereas the actual file should be `%localappdata%\lxss\home\<wsl_username>\.profile`.

Windows paths aren't better either:

```
~ $ "/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe" /mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
Unable to translate current working directory. Using C:\Users\Admin
```

This opens up `C:\mnt\c\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, which is again the wrong path.

Is there a way I can have a correct, msys2-like path integration on WSL?

Comment: @Seth Edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need something along the lines of `cygpath` from Cygwin, unfortunately there isn't a port of this to WSL yet... Then you could just run:

```
cd /
notepad.exe $(cygpath /etc/hosts)
```

For now, the closest substitute for `cygpath` at the moment is small program posted on redit called [win2lin.exe](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/642dru/i_made_a_wrapper_for_running_ubuntu_programs_on/).

For another reference, you can see the shell script that Atom (the text editor) just included with their newest version, [atom.sh](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/b5c4493f5776dad0705dd6df31d562287447ac4d/resources/win/atom.sh).

Or if you wanted to use nodejs and don't mind hardcoding your username, you could write:

```
var p = require("path")
var path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop"
var sepa = path.split(p.win32.sep)
var newS = [].concat([sepa[0].toLowerCase()], sepa.slice(1))
var newP = "/mnt/" + p.posix.join.apply(p.posix, newS).replace(":", "")
// newP == "/mnt/c/Users/me/Desktop
```

For now, the easiest workaround is to make sure the windows binary you want to use is in your path (you can even use a symlink to the .exe to keep your path clean) and then cd to /mnt/c/PathToFileYouWantToEdit, then run your program like: `atom.exe myExampleFile`.

```
cd /mnt/c/Some/Path
notepad.exe SomeFile
```

If your goal is to edit files that are inside WSL but not accessible outside (everything outside of WSL's /mnt) then the easiest way is to install a WebDAV server inside of WSL allowing r/w access to /, and map that WebDAV server to a windows drive letter.